# Why doesn't [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")] allow all requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors

We have decorated a public web API controller with an [`[EnableCors('*', '*', '*')]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn308848(v=vs.118)).

My expectation would be that for the endpoints contained in that web API controller class, CORS is completely allowed and not restricted in any way. Yet, I see the response to Chrome's preflight `OPTIONS` request only contains the following CORS-related headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Consequently, the actual `POST` request I am sending from within Chrome (by means of [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) fails, with the following message getting logged to the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://...' from origin 'https://...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**Am I misunderstanding the meaning of the `EnableCors` attribute, or should I go look for any global settings that might override what I'm setting in said attribute for the controller class?**

---

EDIT: Based upon the answers so far, here are some more things I have tried:

- As described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#Directives), the origin `*` cannot be used if credentials are sent along with the call. [Another MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials) is more explicit about there being a `withCredentials` flag that should not be set to `true`. Now, I have set `withCredentials` in the `xhrFields` property of the config object to [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to `false`, and my request wouldn't send any cookies or an auth header, anyway. Yet, the described error keeps occurring.
- CORS appears to be correctly initialized, as the `HttpConfiguration.EnableCors` method is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things for the attribute to work [source documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#scope)

In App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Basically here you configure the application to enable cors configuration. It's important to be done before any route configurations.

using System.Web.Http;

```
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // This is the key line
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And then

using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

```
namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to check whether we have such a call to the `EnableCors` method, or anything that looks like the `MapHttpRoute` you show where that `EnableCors` call could be inserted.

Comment: Both pieces of code are present in our application (the initial call and the attribute).

Answer (score 2):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` doesn't allow the value of `*` if you're using credentials.

Allowing all origins with any kind of credentials or user identification is a horrible security flaw, and browsers try to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Credentials being identified as such how? As an `Authorization` header? Also, is there some official documentation of some kind to back up this statement?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It's a bit browser specific. Mozilla has https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin, and that's usually used as the go-to description of HTTP etc. The exact details don't matter much - the browser is trying to help you, but it can't do magic. Never allow untrusted origins on requests that are in any way linkable to a user or personal data of any kind. Authorization headers don't matter - the caller has to supply them. Cookies do, because they're sent _automatically by the browser_. That's how the exploits work.

Comment: I now explicitly set `withCredentials` in the `xhrFields` property of `$.ajax` to `false` (as is kind of described on a [troubleshooting page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials) linked to from the page you linked to), yet the described CORS error remains. With that said, [another Mozilla docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) says "Credentials are cookies, authorization headers or TLS client certificates.", so it's apparently not quite true that "Authorization headers ...

Comment: ... don't matter". Yet, this doesn't solve or explain my issue, as this very first request I'm sending doesn't come with any authorization headers.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This might be a Chrome oddity. Have you tried another browser (Firefox might not help anymore, since CORS is in Webkit)? Have you tried using an actual origin instead of `*`? It might also be necessary to include the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header.